# Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at cljs.closure/build (closure.clj:319 3). :bundle-cmd :none failed -- clojurescript with webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, clojurescript, npx, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I'm trying to run the official example https://clojurescript.org/guides/webpack on windows and I get the following error when I execute it:

```
Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at cljs.closure/run-bundle-cmd (closure.clj:3037).
:bundle-cmd :none failed
```

I the full report says the following:

```
"[webpack-cli] [31mUnknown command 'out/index.js'[39m\n[webpack-cli] [31mRun 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options[39m\n"
```

I tried changing the suggested "npx" and "webpack" commands with:

`"npx.cmd"`

and with the possibles absolute paths:

`"C:/Users/usuario/AppData/Roaming/npm/npx.cmd"`
and

`"C:/Program Files/nodejs/npx.cmd"`

...the same for "webpack"

Also tried changing 'out/index.js' to './out/index.js' and using {:deps {org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.10.773"}}} version instead of 1.10.741 suggested in the tutorial.

Any idea for what is going on?

Comment: Can you share you build config? Looks like you have an incorrect `:bundle-cmd :none` somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your time @ThomasHeller!! Do you know why this configuration works and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Make the changes suggested by this post https://dev.to/romanliutikov/integrating-clojurescript-with-javascript-tooling-3799 and it works.

I changed `:bundle-cmd` to `:none ["C:/Program Files/nodejs/npx.cmd" "C:/Users/usuario/AppData/Roaming/npm/webpack.cmd" "--mode=development"]`

and add the following webpack.config.js
`module.exports = { entry: "./out/index.js", output: { path: __dirname, filename: "bundle.js" } }`